# Why does RabbitMQ becomes unresponsive?

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, connection, erlang, message-bus

RabbitMQ 3.7.13 on Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 32GB RAM 48GB page file

Very low utilization - 10 queues , 20 clients , hundreds of messages per day , < 1MB size

Ran fine for 1 year then started becoming unresponsive in a consistent pattern :

1. Restart RabbitMQ Windows Service
2. RabbitMQ accepts new connections and processes messages
3. Connections/sockets start ramping from 940 up to max 7280 in ~10 mins
4. RabbitMQ stops accepting new connections and becomes unresponsive, dashboard shows 500 Internal Server error

When this started happening 2 weeks ago , restarting service would buy about 24 hours of working time before Rabbit became unresponsive again.  But that progressively decreased until now a restart only provides 10 mins uptime.

Looking at server memory history shows some occasional spikes to max capacity.

What could be causing this ? What are some diagnostic techniques to apply ?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html

Comment: Please ask here and provide your Erlang version - https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users